# Trying to integrate CKEditor in a php page

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate CKEditor into my simple CMS. I got it to show up on the page, but it's just above everything. I'm wondering how to get it into the correct spot, below my title textbox? Here is my code:

```
require_once 'conn.php';
include_once 'ckeditor/ckeditor.php';
$CKEditor = new CKEditor();
$CKEditor->editor('body');
$title= '';
$body= '';
$article= '';
$author_id= '';
if (isset($_GET['a'])
    and $_GET['a'] == 'edit'
    and isset($_GET['article'])
    and $_GET['article']) {
        $sql = "SELECT title, body, author_id FROM cms_articles " .
        "WHERE article_id=" . $_GET['article'];
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or
            die ('Could not retrieve article data: ' . mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $title = $row['title'];
        $body = $row['body'];
        $article = $_GET['article'];
        $author_id = $row['author_id'];
    }
    require_once 'header.php';
?>
<form method="post" action="transact-article.php">
    <h2>Compose Article</h2>
    <p>
        Title: <br />
        <input type="text" class="title" name="title" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Body: <br />
        <textarea class="body" name="body" id="body" rows="10" cols="60"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($body); ?></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="article" value="' .
            $article . "\" />\n";
            if ($_SESSION['access_lvl'] < 2) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="' .
                $author_id . "\" />\n";
            }
            if ($article) {
                echo '<input type="submit" class="submit" name="action" ' .
                "value=\"Save Changes\" />";
            } else {
                echo '<input type="submit" class="submit" name="action" ' .
                "value=\"Submit New Article\" />";
            }
        ?>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I changed the id of the BODY: textarea to ckeditor and took out the size fields, and it put it in place. But I have another instance of the editor still open at the top of the page. ?

Comment: What code do you use to replace CKEditor? Is it possible to see this page? The (full) rendered HTML would be more useful then the source here, your problem is unlikely with PHP and even if it is, you usually can find the best clues in the rendered HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I could post a screenshot, but I'm not really sure how. ?

Comment: Don't paste a screenshot please - use the View Source feature in your browser, and post the relevant section of HTML (i.e. the HTML/JS generated by this PHP library) and format it in code tags, as you've done for your PHP (cc @Nenotlep).

Comment: Also, don't go live with this code until you've fixed the potential SQL injection vulnerabilities; where you have user input, it _must_ be cleaned with `mysql_real_escape_string`. Better yet, switch to PDO or MySQLi, and use parameterisation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't think you need the PHP library. Just add

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    Editable text
</div>
```

as your editable and then just the script to get it running:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

That said, you may be able to pass the `id` of your textarea to the PHP library. To avoid confusion with the `body` tag, rename the `id` and `name` of this control to `editable_content` or similar. And as I mention above, try using a `div` instead.

Comment: Agreed, this might be the best way to go, simply learning and using the pure JavaScript of CKEditor and building around it. That way you know everything that's going on and have a good grasp on the situation, both in the fronted HTML/JS implementation and the backend PHP that saves the sent content. It's what I do for asp.net.